# How to retrieve multiple data from jsonb column in postgres?

Tags: json, regex, postgresql

In PostgreSQL database I have a json column called `json`. Data inside look like below:

```
{
    "Version": "0.0.0.1",
    "Items": [
        {
            "Id": "40000000-0000-0000-0000-000000141146",
            "Name": "apple",
            "Score": 64,
            "Value": 1430000
        },
        {
            "Id": "40000000-0000-0000-0000-000000141147",
            "Name": "grapefruit",
            "Score": 58,
            "Value": 1190000
        },
        {
            "Id": "40000000-0000-0000-0000-000000141148",
            "Name": "mango",
            "Score": 41,
            "Value": 170000
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is retrieving all `Score` data from `Items` elements.

I was trying to use SQL code:

```
select
substring(json ->> 'Items' from '"Score": (\d*),') as score
from vegetables;
```

However that returns just the score from first element instead of 3. I was trying to use '\g' flag which supposed to find all results globally, but the code was not working.

Could anyone advise how to do that properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. you should add the desired output also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the data type of `json` field is `jsonb` then no need to use substring or regex, simply `lateral join` with `jsonb_array_elements` will do the required things for you. Try below query.

```
select x->>'Score' "Score" from vegetables 
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json->'Items') x
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8dbcfd23363dc1e3a3a88f0df815f611)